# Dresses of Catherine the Great

Tags: russia

How many dresses did Catherine the Great have in her wardrobe just before she died. I have a clue that one of their lovers took notes. I'm still researching and I will post if I find something.

Comment: Hello @Dimitar Nikolov, welcome to History StackExchange. I have edited your question to fit in better with History: StackExchange rules.

Comment: Please post the supposed clue if you want to see movement on this question.